# c++ - Checking if an Object is in empty state

Tags: c++, object, state

I need to check if my object `Course` is in a safe empty state.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
const bool Course::isEmpty() const {
        if (Course() == nullptr) {

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Constructors:

```
Course::Course() {
        courseTitle_ = new char[21]; // name
        courseTitle_ = '\0';
        credits_ = 0;//qtyNeeded
        studyLoad_ = 0;//quantity


        strcpy(courseCode_, "");//sku

    }
    Course::Course(const char* courseCode, const char* courseTitle, int credits , int studyLoad ) {
        strcpy(courseCode_, courseCode);
        courseTitle_ = new char[21];
        strcpy(courseTitle_, courseTitle);
        studyLoad_ = studyLoad;
        credits_ = credits;
    }
```

Apprently, Doing course() == nullptr is not truly checking if the object is in safe empty state, also checking individual variables if they are set to 0 will not work in my program. i need to check if the entire object was set to a safe empty state.

Edit: Some of you are asking what my empty() function is suppose to use. There is a tester that is suppose to test if my isEmpty() works well.

```
bool isEmptyTest0() {
    // empty test
    sict::Course c0;
    return c0.isEmpty();
}

bool isEmptyTest1() {
    // empty test
    sict::Course c0("", "title", 3, 3);
    return c0.isEmpty();
}

bool isEmptyTest2() {
    // empty test
    sict::Course c0("code", "", 3, 3);
    return c0.isEmpty();
}

bool isEmptyTest3() {
    // empty test
    sict::Course c0("code", "title", -1, 3);
    return c0.isEmpty();
}

bool isEmptyTest4() {
    // empty test
    sict::Course c0("code", "title", 3, -1);
    return c0.isEmpty();
}

bool regularInitTest() {
    // regular
    sict::Course c5("OOP244", "Object-Oriented Programming in C++", 1, 4);
    return (!c5.isEmpty()
        && !strcmp("OOP244", c5.getCourseCode())
        && !strcmp("Object-Oriented Programming in C++", c5.getCourseTitle())
        && (c5.getCredits() == 1)
        && c5.getStudyLoad() == 4
        );
}
```

Note that in `regularInitTest()` my assignment operators work fine, but it never passes `!c5.isEmpty()` because it fails. Hopefully i explained it correctly.

Comment: Define _"safe empty state"_

Comment: It's hard to understand what you actually need. To clarify it, could you please give an example (full C++ source code) of an object in a safe empty state? Could you please give an example of an object not in a safe empty state?

Comment: And define context in which you would use your state check

Comment: Thats the issue, I dont have an example or i would replicate it. Here is how it is exactly defined in my handout:
Also:
- isEmpty returns bool
isEmpty returns true if the Course object is in a safe empty state, false otherwise

This is an assignment. When i emailed my prof this is what he said about the way i did it:
This is not the correct way to deal with the concept of an empty state.

Comment: I'm guessing the brackets in `if (Course() == nullptr)` are a problem. You construct an empty Course object, which you then test again nullptr. I'm not quite sure what you intended to do, but probably not this.

Comment: `courseTitle_ = '\0';` should be `courseTitle_[0] = '\0';`. You're overwriting the address of your `new` char array with the address of a char literal. This causes at best a memory leak and probably later a segmentation fault.

Comment: @andirew1990: It looks like only your professor knows what he means by *safe empty state*. You should ask him for clarification. If you don't understand his reply, ask him again and again until he is able to explain in a way you understand.

Comment: Im specifically talking about my isEmpty() function. how can i check if the object is in safe empty state.

Comment: @pts is there anything i can say to him to get a clearer answer. He is dodging and refusing to give me any more hints and asking me to figure it out myself.

Comment: Seems like professor expects all the isEmptyTest functions to return true. The construction parameters look invalid for all of those.

Comment: @KeithM So yes, here is how he tests if all our functions and constructors work, i passed all the`isEmptyTest` ones except `regularInitTest()`
http://puu.sh/qfAky/0431e8a833.png because in regularInitTest() when it checks for c5.isEmpty() it returns false, so then it thinks it failed.

Comment: @andirew1990: Like this: I'd like to understand what you mean by *safe empty state*, in particular the word *safe*. I wasn't able to find it in the textbook. Could you please point me to the part of the textbook which explains *safe empty state*? If it's not in the textbook, could you please refer me to some code examples of *safe empty state* and *non-safe empty state*, so that I can see the difference?

Comment: @pts nowhere in MY online textbook does it ever mention how to check if the OBJECT is in safe empty state, it only mentions how to set all ur member variables to safe empty states in ur constructor. Here is where it is mentioned: https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~oop244/pages/content/cppst.html#saf

Comment: @andirew1990 C++ is not Java, C, or JavaScript. You didn't understand how things are done in C++ yet. One of the main reasons for this is that "online textbook" is terrible. You don't want to solve your own problem. Instead you want to take a step back and learn C++ properly.

Comment: To me, it looks like `isEmpty` is supposed to test for a valid state. The first four tests each pass an invalid value as one of the constructor arguments and expect a "bad/empty" course object.

Comment: @mash thats what my school provides.

Comment: @andirew1990 yeah most schools don't know what they're doing when it comes to cs. Just learn from a proper textbook such as "[Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition)](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/)"

Comment: @andirew1990: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think this is a valid question. For your next question, you can get an answer easier and faster if you provide more information in the question. For example, you can provide a link to all the source code you have, and a link to the section of the textbook you are reading, and a link to the full text of the assignment. Provide as much information as you can, so less clarification is needed.

Comment: @pts Here is my assignment handout https://my.senecacollege.ca/bbcswebdav/pid-6692120-dt-content-rid-14674800_2/courses/OOP244SDD.04268.2164/FinalProject_S2016_M1%203_OOP244.pdf

Course.CPP : http://paste.ofcode.org/8gPKdqnGJypHzz7iSd2eA
ScmApp.CPP:http://paste.ofcode.org/ijACBUbWjvpZbHjTYzMEmQ
CourseTester.CPP: http://paste.ofcode.org/35V6rvXGbG3HYcHVfgxyikH
Test.cpp:http://paste.ofcode.org/tSe8D385QZewqqDUZV3yt2

Answer (score 0):

Most probably here is what you should do to make the tests pass.

In the 2nd (4-argument) constructor, do some checking of the input, e.g. check if `credits` is positive. Do check all arguments for all possible errors you can imagine, including those in isEmptyTest0..4. If there is an error, initialize the object the same way as the 1st (0-argument) constructor does. If there is no error, initialize the data members from the arguments.

Here is how to implement the `isEmpty` method: it should return true iff all the data members of the object have the empty/zero/default value, as initialized by the 1st (0-argument) constructor.

The notion *safe empty state* in itself still doesn't make sense, but the concept the professor is trying to teach does make sense. I'll try to summarize my understanding here. Constructors can receive invalid arguments, based on which it's not possible to initialize a meaningful and valid object. The programmer should add code for error checking and handling everywhere in the program, including constructors. There are multiple approaches to do input validation and error handling in constructors, e.g. 1. throwing an exception; 2. aborting the entire program with an error message; 3. initializing the object to a special, invalid state; 4. initializing the object to a special, empty state. (This is also an option, but it's strongly disrecommended: 5. keep some data members of the object uninitialized.) Each of these approaches have pros and cons. In this assignment, the professor wants you to implement #4. See the 2nd paragraph in my answer how to do it.

When the professor asks for a *safe empty state*, he most probably means that you should be doing input validation in the constructor, and in case of an error doing #4 rather than #5.

Comment: Tried it, with no luck. It still fails the regularInitTest()

http://paste.ofcode.org/34pfSV9Jmdg9PUgjVC8XP8k

Comment: Thank you for posting your code! You were doing it differently than my suggestion. I suggested this: even if there is an error only in 1 argument, all arguments should be set to empty. If it still fails after fixing this, and you are not able to figure out why, I think you should post a separate question on StackOverflow, asking ``why does regularInitTest fail?''. Make sure that you include all C++ source files (not just snippets) in your new question, so others can compile and run your code.

Comment: One of the goals of the course is to make you practice debugging and fixing code. To get the maximum out of it, you should take initiative and think about it: ``is there any way I can make these tests succeed?'', come up with many ideas, try all of them, and if none of them work, only then ask the question, and in the question include everything you have tried so far and why and how they didn't work. You are doing it right if it's you (not the people trying to answer your question) who is spending most time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [pts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97248/pts) that *safe empty state* is ill-defined.

The missing principle, it seems to me after reading the comments, is *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization* ([RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)).  A constructor is a transaction, in a way: you get either

- a valid object, or
- an exception.

*Valid* here is defined by the class.  Usually it means that the passed parameters were incorporated into the object, and all required resources were successfully allocated and/or found.

Aborting the program is rarely an option, and returning an error (from a constructor) never is.  Constructing an invalid object is usually done only in environments where exceptions are prohibited.

There is a special case: the default constructor.  Sometimes it's desirable to "make an empty" thing that will be fully initialized later.

Consider `std::string`.   It can be constructed with a value, and throws an exception if memory cannot be allocated.  Or it can be constructed without a value, and later assigned one.  Your class could be similar, in which case *safe empty* just means a state that the user would be happy to destroy when calling the "init" function.  You don't have to test every member variable; you just have to check something that will be true only for a completely initialized object.

Then there's the question of "is valid".  An "empty" object can be "initialized", but it can't be used.  It's not "valid" for use until fully initialized, whether at construction, or via the 2-step with a default constructor and a subsequent "init".

There is a widely accepted idiom for testing whether an object is "is valid" or not: a user-defined conversion to `void *`:

```
...
public:
  operator void*() { return is_valid()? this : nullptr; }
...
```

where `is_valid()` may be a private function.  With that in place, the user can test his instantiated object thus:

```
class A;
A foo();
...
if (!foo) { foo.open(...); }
```

I know I haven't answered your question, exactly.  I hope I've provided some background that makes it easier for your to answer it yourself.